# Flutter Stripe throws StripeException when Presenting Payment Sheet

Tags: android, ios, flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement a Stripe payment system in my flutter app using the stripe_payment package. In my code, I call Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(...), however when I try to call Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(...) just a few lines later, I get this error:

```
flutter: StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: No payment sheet has been initialized yet, message: No payment sheet has been initialized yet, stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))
```

Here is my code:

```
Future<void> makePayment() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        '${firebaseFunction}');

    final response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    this.paymentIntentData = json.decode(response.body);

    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['paymentIntent'],
            applePay: true,
            googlePay: true,
            style: ThemeMode.dark,
            merchantCountryCode: 'UK',
            merchantDisplayName: 'Test Payment Service'));
    setState(() {});

    print('initialised');
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
      setState(() {
        paymentIntentData = null;
      });
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Payment Successful!'),
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    // await displayPaymentSheet();
  }
```

And here is my node.js code (accessed through url):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey);

exports.stripePayment = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 170,
        currency: 'usd'
    },
    function(err, paymentIntent) {
        if (err != null) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json({
                paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Why doesn't the Payment Sheet initialize (or stay initialized) when I try to use the presentPaymentSheet method?

Comment: @ZackHossian did you solve the problem?

Comment: @ZackHossain did you solve this, I have the same issue

Comment: I am facing the same issue with an iOS device. it works well on Android.

Comment: Any fix, I am also facing the same issue on IOS

Answer (score 37):

The Paymentsheet worked on android but did not work in iPhone for me.
It took me hours to find this answer (was struggling as well).
There needs to be an update in the stripe documentation but when initializing Stripe you will need to initialize Stripe.publishableKey but also initialize Stripe.merchantIdentifier

**EXAMPLE**

First you will need initialize Stripe in your main function. (Like shown below).

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Stripe.publishableKey = stripePublishableKey;
  Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'any string works';
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  runApp(const App());
}
```

Then the paymentsheet will appear without stating `No payment sheet has been initialized yet`

Comment: you definitely saved me!!

Comment: I am facing the same issue with an iOS device. it works well on Android.

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Comment: Not working for me IOS

Answer (score 3):

In case someone ends up here in the future and you've tried everything including adding extra settings in your main file, try also changing your `customerId` field in the `Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet` to `null` or some existing Id. What I found is for android it easily works but with iOS it needs a proper customerId or null.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with an iOS device. it works well on Android.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as I was following the official documentation found [here](https://docs.page/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/sheet#1-set-up-stripe-server-side-client-side). What was causing this problem was the value of `paymentIntentClientSecret`.

Try changing:

```
paymentIntentClientSecret: data['paymentIntent']
```

To:

```
paymentIntentClientSecret: data['client_secret'],
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have checked out all the above but nothing worked:
just set `allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true,`

```
 await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
    merchantDisplayName: 'Prospects',
    customerId: data['customer'],
    allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true, // set this to true
    paymentIntentClientSecret: data['client_secret'],
    customerEphemeralKeySecret: data['ephemeralKey'],
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

stripe version

```yaml
flutter_stripe: ^7.0.0
```

```dart
await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            merchantDisplayName: 'APP',
            paymentIntentClientSecret: model.clientSecret,
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: eph.secret,
            customerId: model.customer,
            style: ThemeMode.system,
            billingDetails: billingDetail,
            customFlow: true),
      );
```

Adding the attribute 'customFlow' solves my problem

```dart
customFlow: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply include this code within the catch statement :

```
      if (e is _$_StripeException && e.error.localizedMessage == 'The payment flow has been canceled') {
    // Handle canceled payment
    print('Payment canceled by the user');
    // You can show a message to the user or navigate back to the previous screen
  } else {
    // Handle other errors
    print('Error during payment: $e');
    // You might want to show a generic error message or log the error for debugging
  }
```