# Stripe wont intialize paymentsheet

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe to my flutter app, but i am running in to this issue:

```
StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: No payment sheet has been initialized yet, message: No payment sheet has been initialized yet, stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))
```

My current code is:

```
Future<void> makePayment() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
        api_string,
      ),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
      body: json.encode({"Amount": "250"}),
    );

    var data = json.decode(response.body);

    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret: data['clientSecret'],
        merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter test app',
        applePay: true,
        googlePay: true,
        style: ThemeMode.dark,
        testEnv: true,
        merchantCountryCode: 'DK',
      ),
    );
    setState(() {});

    await displayPaymentSheet();
  }

  Future<void> displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I have checked the official flutter_stripe documentation, but the example with my API changed gives the same error, and my api return "clientSecret": Secret}

Comment: Have you tried any of the proposed solutions to a very similar question asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69151587/flutter-stripe-throws-stripeexception-when-presenting-payment-sheet
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, the fix was to add a merchantId to the Stripe initialization

Comment: Nope. It did not work for me. :(